# Disable all drop downs using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html form and it has few SELECT drop downs.
How can i disable all SLECT drop downs of the form in one shot using `JQuery`?

```
form id : mainId
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$('#mainId select').prop('disabled', true)`.

Comment: [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $('#mainId select').prop('disabled',true);
```

use `prop()` if you are using jquery 1.6+ version

Comment: Learning guy here, I suggested him to use `.attr()` so is that fine? Or should I take back my answer

Comment: well, as of old version of jquery , before 1.6, `attr()` was the only way to change the property value , which did cause inconsitent behaviour, thus `prop()` was introduce in later version, to explicitly retrieve property values.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('select').prop("disabled", true);
```

Or specific:

```
$('#mainId select').prop('disabled',true);
```

The.prop () method:
Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#form-id select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Thanks.